# Why Django can't find the right templates

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I try to learn Django CRUD from this tutorial: https://www.javatpoint.com/django-crud-example My Django version is 2.1.7 and my IDE is VisualStudio. When I run the project all the pages have an error. the error cames bellow.

```
 TemplateDoesNotExist at /index
show.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:52322/index
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
show.html
Exception Location: E:\Django_Try\DjangoWebProject5\DjangoWebProject5\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  E:\Django_Try\DjangoWebProject5\DjangoWebProject5\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.6
Python Path:    
['E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5',
 '',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python36_64',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5\\env',
 'E:\\Django_Try\\DjangoWebProject5\\DjangoWebProject5\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 5 Mar 2019 22:43:24 +0000
```

I added my Urls bellow:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.urls import path  
from employee import views  

urlpatterns = [  
    path('index', views.show), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),  
    path('emp', views.emp),  
    path('show',views.show),  
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit), 
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update),  
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.destroy),  
]
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from employee.forms import EmployeeForm  
from employee.models import Employee  
# Create your views here.  
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})  
def show(request):  
    employees = Employee.objects.all()  
    return render(request,"show.html",{'employees':employees})  
def edit(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    return render(request,'edit.html', {'employee':employee})  
def update(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    form = EmployeeForm(request.POST, instance = employee)  
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return redirect("/show")  
    return render(request, 'edit.html', {'employee': employee})  
def destroy(request, id):  
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=id)  
    employee.delete()  
    return redirect("/show")
```

setting:

```
"""
Django settings for DjangoWebProject5 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '65ccf984-10e5-4c13-ab4d-9c0cf30e8b04'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'employee',  
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoWebProject5.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoWebProject5.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

My structure screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xRB0xcnkplZ4ktiyEblkMVeyJ1SpATDc

I think the error says the template does not exist but the templates exist. Please inform me what is wrong in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Here, your troubles come from your understanding of your project architecture.
As you can see in your screenshoot [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xRB0xcnkplZ4ktiyEblkMVeyJ1SpATDc)

Your template files are in the */DjangoWebProject5/employee/templates/**employee/**

So you have too call them with the right path like 'employee/index.html'

```
def emp(request):  
    if request.method == "POST":  
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            try:  
                form.save()  
                return redirect('/show')  
            except:  
                pass  
    else:  
        form = EmployeeForm()  
    return render(request,'employee/index.html',{'form':form})  ## Here 'employee/index.html'
```

You can fix that on all your views.

Comment: Your answer is a bit short. Can you please explain more for your answer?

Comment: Yes, i will try.

Comment: But I added the employee to all of the views and still I get 404 error!!

Answer (score 1):

[Check this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#the-dirs-option)

It appears that TEMPLATE_DIRS was used prior to 1.8 but in the current version it has changed to a DIRS option in the TEMPLATES setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        '/home/html/templates/lawrence.com',
        '/home/html/templates/default',
    ],
},

]
```